# Crear 'struct' con campos string de una longitud o array char con una longitud

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Quiero crear un tipo 'struct' compuesto por unos campos que debe ser un array de char con una longitud determinada o un string con una longitud determinada. 
Actualmente lo tengo declarado de esta manera:

```
public struct Header
    {
        public char[] entityCode;
        public char[] date;
        public char[] numberProcess; 
        public char[] numberEnd;  
        public char[] filler;           
    }
```

Donde cada uno debe tener las siguientes longitudes: entityCode = longitud 6, date = longitud 6, numberProcess = longitud 4, numberEnd = longitud 3, filler = longitud 50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que quieres se llama técnicamente [Buffer de tamaño fijo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers), y para poder crear un buffer de este tipo se debe usar la instrucción [`fixed`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement), por ejemplo en tu caso el primer campo se definiría como:

```
public fixed char entityCode[6];
```

Pero hay un problema. Copio de la documentación:

> En el código seguro, un struct de C# que contiene una matriz no contiene los elementos de matriz. En su lugar, el struct contiene una referencia a los elementos. Puede insertar una matriz de tamaño fijo en un struct cuando se usa en un bloque de código no seguro.

Con lo que la definición de tu estructura quedaría asi:

```
public unsafe struct Header
{
    public fixed char entityCode[6];
    public fixed char date[6];
    public fixed char numberProcess[4];
    public fixed char numberEnd[3];
    public fixed char filler[50];
}
```

Debes tener en cuenta que al ser código `unsafe`, tu eres responsable de gestionar los posibles errores, como por ejemplo que sobrepases el límite del array.

Comment: Gracias, como me advertías me indica el siguiente mensaje a la hora de compilar: "El código no seguro sólo puede aparecer si se compila con /unsafe".

Comment: ¿ Como podría saber la longitud entonces del struct en char o bytes en el caso que no usara fixed ?

Comment: @Popularfan fíjate en la documentación que te enlacé de Buffer de tamaño fijo. En la parte `Comentarios` te pone un ejemplo de estructura y explica como se calcula su tamaño.

Comment: Ok gracias de nuevo